# Ultrasonic Distance sensor reading to Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, arduino, distance

I might be going about this in the wrong way but here goes. I am currently trying to post readings from my Ultrasonic Distance Sensor/Arduino Yun to the Parse.com website. From there I shall take the data into Xcode and create an app but I know how to do that.

My main problem is currently combining the Parse tutorial code and my current Ultrasonic distance sensor code. I currently have the sensor doing exactly what I want and printing the correct reading in the serial monitor, however I want the data it is printing to be shown online.

Is this easily done?

I am currently able to post my data onto Data.Sparkfun.com however when it comes to scraping that to Xcode it get's extremely messy.

I hope this is an easy solve, here is the current code I have working for my sensor:

```
#include <Process.h>
#include <NewPing.h>

////////////////
// Pin Inputs //
////////////////
const int triggerPin = 3;
#define TRIGGER_PIN  2  // Arduino pin tied to trigger pin on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define ECHO_PIN     4  // Arduino pin tied to echo pin on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define MAX_DISTANCE 500 // Maximum distance we want to ping for (in centimeters). Maximum sensor distance is rated at 400-500cm.
int i=0;
int current = 0;
int low = 10000;

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);

String name = "Yun-anon";
boolean newName = true;

void setup() 
{
  Bridge.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Setup Input Pins:
  pinMode(triggerPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(current, INPUT_PULLUP);
  //pinMode(lightPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  Serial.println("=========== Ready to Stream ===========");
  Serial.println("Press the button (D3) to send an update");
  Serial.println("Type your name, followed by '!' to update name");
}

void loop()
{  
  delay(50);                      // Wait 50ms between pings (about 20 pings/sec). 29ms should be the shortest delay between pings.
  unsigned int uS = sonar.ping(); // Send ping, get ping time in microseconds (uS).
  int y = uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;

  int x = y/2;


  current = x;
  current=map(current,9,2,50,800);
    Serial.println(current);
  if (current < low){
    low = current;
  } 
  delay(1000);

  // If the trigger pin (3) goes low, send the data.
  if (!digitalRead(triggerPin))
  {
    // Gather Data
    fieldData[0] = String(analogRead(current));
    //fieldData[1] = String(digitalRead(switchPin));
    //fieldData[2] = name;

    // Post Data
    Serial.println("Posting Data!");
    postData(); // the postData() function does all the work, 
                // see below.
    delay(1000);
  }

  // Check for a new name input:
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c == '!')
    {
      newName = true;
      Serial.print("Your name is ");
      Serial.println(name);
    }
    else if (newName)
    {
      newName = false;
      name = "";
      name += c;
    }
    else
    {
      name += c;
    }
  }

}

void postData()
{
  Process phant; // Used to send command to Shell, and view response
  String curlCmd; // Where we'll put our curl command
  String curlData[NUM_FIELDS]; // temp variables to store curl data

  // Construct curl data fields
  // Should look like: --data "fieldName=fieldData"
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_FIELDS; i++)
  {
    curlData[i] = "--data \"" + fieldName[i] + "=" + fieldData[i] + "\" ";
  }

  // Construct the curl command:
  curlCmd = "curl ";
  curlCmd += "--header "; // Put our private key in the header.
  curlCmd += "\"Phant-Private-Key: "; // Tells our server the key is coming
  curlCmd += privateKey; 
  curlCmd += "\" "; // Enclose the entire header with quotes.
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_FIELDS; i++)
    curlCmd += curlData[i]; // Add our data fields to the command
  curlCmd += phantURL + publicKey; // Add the server URL, including public key

  // Send the curl command:
  Serial.print("Sending command: ");
  Serial.println(curlCmd); // Print command for debug
  phant.runShellCommand(curlCmd); // Send command through Shell

  // Read out the response:
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  // Use the phant process to read in any response from Linux:
  while (phant.available())
  {
    char c = phant.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to upload a new reading to parse every 50ms ? You have a couple of other delays in there too. I'm not really clear on exactly what your problem is - unrelated to the sensor part...

Comment: @Wain The ultrasonic sensor is taking readings ever 50ms yes however I am only wishing to push the data to Parse.com when I press the button. At this moment in time I able to print the readings in the serial monitor however I am unable to get the data to post on parse.com. I hope this helps and thank you for your comment!